# Animate nsmenuitem

Tags: cocoa

I would like to animate nsmenuitem that I have for my app (preferably use coreanimation).  I have seen the menu item animating in CloudApp, dropbox, Time Machine and Syncing MobileMe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSMenuItem can have a custom view. In that case, is your responsibility drawing the item. A custom view can be easily animated (adding a progress indicator or whatever you need).

Check [NSMenuItem reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html): `-[NSMenuItem view]`, `-[NSMenuItem setView]` and its associated code samples.